# AWS CloudFormation Restricting SNS to specific SQS Queues only

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'm modifying an AWS CloudFormation template with the intention of ensuring that **SNS Topic A** is the only topic that can publish to **SQS Queue 1** and **SQS Queue 2**.
This is what I have:

```
SomeOtherQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
InboundQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
InboundCopyQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue

InboundTopic:
  Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
  Properties:
    Subscription:
    - Endpoint:
        Fn::GetAtt:
        - InboundQueue
        - Arn
       Protocol: sqs

InboundQueuePolicy:
  Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
  Properties:
    PolicyDocument:
      Version: '2012-10-17'
      Id: InboundQueuePolicy
      Statement:
      - Sid: Allow-SendMessage-To-Inbound-Queue-Only
        Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          Service:
            - sns.amazonaws.com
        Action:
          - sqs:SendMessage
        Resource: "*"
    Queues:
      - Ref: InboundQueue
      - Ref: InboundCopyQueue
```

The above defines a set of queues, a topic with a subscription to some the relevant queues and a queue policy that is meant to restrict which topic can publish to the referenced queues.

What I'm trying to understand is how to go about ensuring that *InboundQueuePolicy* applies to *InboundTopic* only. I cannot seem to find the correct syntax for referencing *InboundTopic* as the resource for *InboundQueuePolicy*.

Any assistance with getting the correct syntax would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could add a condition to your policy that uses the `aws:SourceArn` key. [AWS Global Condition Context Keys - Source ARN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-sourcearn)

Comment: Thanks Jason - I hadn't looked into that. Will try it out and revert.